# How many items should one list row contain?

Tags: lists, listview

How many items are recommended to put in one row of the list? 
Are there any recommendations, how many items should one row contains in the list? A lot of famous e-shops put a lot of items in one row, is this a good practice, or just a saving of space?

I am creating a list page, each item of which contains a lot of information, so decided to show one item on each page that contains image in the right, and title/description on the left... but later I found a lot of similar pages, which show a big image instead of text, and only the title of message

So, are there any recommendations? are big images more informative than smaller image and text? or this is for space economy?

Comment: I feel that you are looking for a catch-all solution, where good design solutions are tailored to the specific problem they are meant to solve. In other words, you will only get useful answers if you explain in details what information you need to present and how important it is to users. There are many strategies that can help with a case like this - like progressive disclosure or plain visual guidance. The ideal answer really depends on your specific case.

Comment: @Izhaki, it is some coupon deals, similar to the given page... So it contains title, description, conditions in which cas coupon will be applied and etc.

Comment: The logiс why pokupon.ua displays a lot of items is because they want user to choose the action. It's hard and not possible to predict which actions will be interested for the user so the display a lot of them.

But they don't use progressive disclosure - it would be much smoother experience for users in their case - a lot of items with images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reservations about "answer"ing this, since as user @Izhaki points out, it depends so much on the context - one cannot really say what looks best without seeing.. anything.

That said - I would suggest that any more than 7 is starting to become untidy.

How do I arrive at that number? I recall that on average people can perceive 7 distinct entities, for example if you hold 5 peas in your hand, show me, and then remove your hand, I can tell you there were 5. If you do it with 9, on average people cannot accurately tell you how many peas you were holding. That's a sort-of justification. Then take this page's navigation for example:

[image: UX Stack Exchange Navigation]

There are six items. It looks pretty good, but imagine having a few more:

[image]

It starts to become unwieldy pretty quickly.

Regarding images, the trend in web design is undeniably toward bigger images, less text, more (or less depending on how you look at it) *design*.

Ultimately though, it's going to depend on your users, so I think the best you can do is just iterate. Try it, and see. *Is there more engagement? Do they find what they're looking for quicker? Do they like it?*